# c# asp.net for append int value to the label id

Tags: c#

I have the following label with ids:

```
<asp:Label ID="FromName0" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="FromName1" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="FromName2" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="FromName3" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="FromName4" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

I want to assign the values to the label ids using for loop.
I am using the following tags in c#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
var label = this.Controls.Find("FromName " + i, true) as Label;
label.Text = Session["DeliverAddress" + i].ToString();
}
```

But ‘Find’ shows error like below:
System.Web.UI.ControlCollections does not have the definition for ‘Find’. But I have already added ‘System.Web.UI’ dll file. Can anyone help me?

I am using dotnet framework 4.0.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this

```
  public  Control[] FlattenHierachy(Control root)
    {
        List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
        list.Add(root);
        if (root.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
            {
                list.AddRange(FlattenHierachy(control));
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control[] allControls = FlattenHierachy(Page);
        foreach (Control control in allControls)
        {
            Label lbl = control as Label;
            if (lbl != null && lbl.ID == "FromName0")
            {
                lbl.ID = "myid";//Do your like stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code can't compile. What is i in this context ? He need to start second loop. Nested loops are not fun !

Comment: I is you custom variable ..remove it ..give a custom name

Comment: But he has count of controls which he is looping-> he can't write the whole control name. He needs to add second loop with your code. If you want to find one control it will work, but this is not the goal here. You can move your code in separate method in which you will take controlName as parameter. You should loop from 1 to count and give the correct names to the method. This will meet the op requirements.

Comment: Add more if else .

Answer (score 0):

Just use : [Here MSDN article about FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Searches the page naming container for a server control with the specified identifier.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   id:
    //     The identifier for the control to be found.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The specified control, or null if the specified control does not exist.
    public override Control FindControl(string id);
```

Here how your code should look like. Just as advice check if the **control is null** or the **session variable is null**, this can give you an exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var label = FindControl("FromName " + i) as Label;

    if(label == null || Session["DeliverAddress" + i] == null)
       continue;

    label.Text = Session["DeliverAddress" + i].ToString();

}
```